# Selenium ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape a website which requires clicking on "View All" buttons in order to view more items in the html. Problem is, none of the solutions I've been finding through google seem to help/be applicable.

The view-all tab has the class "shelf_view-all', but when I pass this to my driver to find the element, I get an error that it's not interactable.

My code is attached below; does anyone have any thoughts on just getting Selenium to click on this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
chromedriver = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
url='https://cn.burberry.com/womens-coats-jackets/#cat3850051'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('shelf_view-all').click()
```

Comment: Update the question with the exact _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_

Answer (score 0):

class `shelf_view-all` return 5 element and you select first element which is not correct target, use

> find_element**s**_by_class_name

or css selector

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('shelf_view-all')[4].click()
# or
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cat3850051 .shelf_view-all').click()
```